# Is incorrect mix of protocol and port in Tomcat a security issue?

Tags: security, tomcat, ssl, https, port

I have enabled Self-signed certificate for Tomcat 6.0.18 in Windows environment. In **server.xml** in **conf** folder of Tomcat, HTTP port is configured at 8080 and HTTPS port at 8443. Everything is working as expected. That is all HTTP requests are getting redirected to HTTPS.

Following are my connector settings for port 8080

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
       connectionTimeout="20000" enableLookups="false" 
       redirectPort="8443" />
```

Following are my connector settings for port 8443

```
<Connector port="8443" 
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
SSLEnabled="true"               
maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" 
keystoreFile="c:\ssl\keystore"
keystorePass="<password>"
clientAuth="false" 
sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

However, when an incorrect mix of protocol and port (`http://localhost:8443`) in Internet Explorer is entered, it shows 5 rectangles.

[image]

And in Firefox it displays a question mark character as below.

[image]

This has come as a security issue to me in security audit. Is this a security issue? Has anyone come across such a issue? Is this a security vulnerability? What is a remedy for this? Any help in this regard is very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Wap Rau

Comment: If it is a security issue, it's not one you can do anything about. You can't change the behaviour of IE and Firefox. Ask the reviewers what security is compromised exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got `SSLEnabled="true"`, `scheme="https"`, and `secure="true"` in your server.xml's SSL `<Connector>`?  Surprised that Tomcat 6 allows insecure connections on what you've defined as a secure Connector.  (According to documentation, `scheme` and `secure` only inform what `isSecure()` and `getScheme()` return from within a Servlet, but perhaps not setting these leads to issues like you're seeing too.)

Assuming you've set the above properly, I would suggest code that intecepts requests and examines both protocol and port and sends a 302 redirect (since you're using Tomcat, that'd be a `response.sendRedirect()`) to the proper protocol/port if necessary.

In this case, a JavaScript redirect (`location.replace()`) might be tempting, but remember that your response is getting mangled, so that's not an option here.  (I only mention this because I almost proposed it as an alternative solution, before catching myself!)

Comment: Thanks for reply, Steve. I have updated my question with settings for port 8443 and 8080 which are same as you have mentioned.